# Can we store photon as energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, photons

I asking this because i think that photon is a force carier for electromagnectic force mean that it have force so why don't we store photon as enegry ?

Comment: This is what a phosphor does.

Comment: We do. Solar panels do exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Solar panel convert photon energy to electric or heat not directly store photon as enegry

Comment: I think your misconception is that there exists a form of energy purer than photons. There is no such thing. You're not getting purer energy. It is the form of energy that other forms of energies strive to be. The universe began as photons and it seems like it will end that way as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The photon is a zero mass particle in the elementary particles table of the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

As such it moves with the velocity of light c, in all inertial systems, and cannot be caught at rest and stored. Totally reflecting cavities have been created and can store photons by continuous reflections , but are not useful for storage of energy, as if the amount of energy carried by the photons became large, the walls would melt and there would be  absorption of photons and not reflection.

The [technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7banBQbALg) is used in smart experiments, but not for storing energy.